# Ordenar registro UI GRID a partir do filtro

Tags: java, angularjs, grid

Ola,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta imagem exibiu apenas os dados que possuem "S", porém, além de exibi-los, preciso ordenar isto apartir do filtro da pesquisa, ou seja, neste caso, o resultado seria algo como: Sleeping / Basketball / Thermal.

Alguem tem algum dica ou um norte pra me ajudar?

Obrigado!